# StackOverFlowError with BigInteger in java

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, biginteger

**Why does this java code throw a `StackOverflowError` exception?**

```
public class factorial2 {

     public BigInteger fact( BigInteger n)
     {
         BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
         if(n.equals("0"))
              return one;
         else
             return n.multiply(fact(n.subtract(one)));      
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {       
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        factorial2 f = new factorial2();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
           BigInteger b = sc.nextBigInteger();
           System.out.println(f.fact(b));
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

I have attempted to generate a factorial using `BigInteger`. But, why does my code give the reference exception on input?

Comment: A BigInteger will never equal `"0"`. Try comparing to `BigInteger.ZERO`.

Comment: Also, there is no need to make your own BigInteger 1 -- use `BigInteger.ONE`.

Comment: thanks a lot. Problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with your base case; `n` (which is a `BigInteger`) will not equal `"0"` (which is a `String`). So you continue to the `else` block, which re-curses. Also, `BigInteger` includes constants for `ONE` and `ZERO` so you could write something like

```
public static BigInteger fact(BigInteger n) {
    if (n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || n.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    else
        return n.multiply(fact(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

***or*** *using* a ternary operation (conditional operator `? :`) like

```
public static BigInteger fact(BigInteger n) {
    return (n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || n.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) ? BigInteger.ONE 
            : n.multiply(fact(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

BigInteger#equals method

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
    // This test is just an optimization, which may or may not help
    if (x == this)
        return true;
    if (!(x instanceof BigInteger))
        return false;
```

This condition is always false

```
if (n.equals("0"))
```

Instead, use

```
if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(n))
```